# Does the order of columns in a composite index affect lookup speed?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

Let's take the following MySQL table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE prices (
  id          INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  countryCode CHAR(2) COLLATE ASCII_BIN NOT NULL,
  productId   INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  merchantId  INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX (countryCode, productId, merchantId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The only lookups I will ever make on this table will be either:

- `WHERE countryCode = ? AND productId = ?`
- `WHERE countryCode = ? AND productId = ? AND merchantId = ?`

The index can therefore be used for all the queries, which is fine.

Not all queries will include a `merchantId`, so this one is best used as the last column in the composite index.

Now regarding the first two columns: **I will never make a lookup on `countryCode` alone or `productId` alone**, so at first glance I would bet that using the index column order `(countryCode, productId, merchantId)` or `(productId, countryCode, merchantId)` should not make any difference for my use case in terms of performance, but I have no theoretical knowledge to back this up.

Given that there are are many more different `productId`s than `countryCode`s, **is there any performance difference (not only `SELECT`, but also `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` speed) to change the order of these two columns in the index, when they are always used together?**

Answer (score 1):

Given that the condition terms are all equals, and the terms are combined with `AND`, there's no significant difference in performance to changing the order of columns in the index.

Think of a telephone book. If I ask you to look up "Smith, John" you look up the Smith section and then among them find John. If the book were organized differently, by first name then by last name, you'd look up the John section and then among them find Smith. Either way, you can narrow down the search quite easily.

Is there a difference? Probably a slight difference, but it doesn't amount to enough to worry about.

If you have conditions that are *not* equals, then the rules change. Put the columns in your equality comparison first in the index, then one column in a range or inequality condition.

You might also like my presentation, [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really). There's also a video recording of me presenting this talk here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct.  As long as your joins are equi-joins (using `=`), then either of the two indexes you mention should be used for the query.  `MerchantId` needs to be the third key after the other two.

There could possibly be some extreme cases with very long keys where the ordering between `CountryCode` and `ProductId` would make a difference -- comparing long strings takes a bit longer than comparing integers.  Those are not concerns for your data structure.

MySQL actually has good [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on the use of composite indexes in queries.